# How can I tell if a SObject field implements a global value set?

Tags: object, salesforce, field

I have multiple fields on a single sObject that all use the same Global Value Set.  I wan't to be able to perform an action, based on the value of these fields.  If a new field were to be added, using the same GVS, I would not want to have to change my code.  How can I tell which GVS a field uses?

Comment: I'm not entirely following your use case. Do you have any code to share? I'm not seeing anything in the docs for seeing if a picklist comes from a global value set. Your best bet is to just use the `getType()` method on the [DescribeFieldResult class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pull the metadata on the field definition via [Tooling REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_overview.htm). Resource URI:

```
/services/data/<api version>/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,Label,DurableId,Metadata+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+DurableId='...'
```

yields this response with `<api_version>` = 46.0 (Ids are redacted, many fields are removed for clarity):

```
{
  "size" : 1,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "FieldDefinition",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "FieldDefinition",
      "url" : "/services/data/v46.0/tooling/sobjects/FieldDefinition/01I..."
    },
    "Id" : "000...",
    "Label" : "State",
    "DurableId" : "01I...00N...",
    "QualifiedApiName" : "State__c",
    "Metadata" : {
      ...
      "valueSet" : {
        "controllingField" : null,
        "restricted" : true,
        "valueSetDefinition" : null,
        "valueSetName" : "usa_states",
        "valueSettings" : null
      },
     ....
    }
  } ]
}
```

If `valueSet` key is present and the child key `valueSetName` has a value other than null, that means this field is a picklist backed by a Global Value Set. The value of `valueSetName` is the name of the Global Value set.

To retrieve the `Metadata` field from `FieldDefinition` entity, your Tooling API query must return exactly 1 record. If more than 1 record would be returned, you'll see a misleading MALFORMED_QUERY error message.

To return exactly 1 record, querying on `DurableId` is one way to go. For standard objects, the value of `DurableId` is easy to construct - it's a concatenation in a format of `<Object Name>.<Field Name>`. For example, with the standard `Account` object, its `Id` field has a durable id value of `Account.Id` and the corresponding REST resource would be

```
/services/data/<api version>/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,Label,DurableId,Metadata+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+DurableId='Account.Id'
```

For custom objects, the value of DurableId has the format of `<object definition id>.<field definition id>` (the period between two ids is intentional). Note: these are not Ids of records (e.g. *instances*) of objects and/or fields; they are Ids of object and field *definitions*.  If we have a custom object `Truck__c` with an id of `01I...` and a custom field `State__c` with an id of `00N...`, the value of `DurableId` will be `01Ixxxxx.00Nyyyy`.

As an alternative to figuring out the DurableId, if you need to pull the metadata of a custom field on a standard or a custom object, it's easier to go against `CustomField` entity via the Tooling API:

```
/services/data/<api version>/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,Metadata,DeveloperName+FROM+CustomField+WHERE+DeveloperName='State'
```

The value of `DeveloperName` is the same as the value of a *Field Name* field on the custom field's definition page in the admin UI.

Comment: Thanks, that's a comprehensive answer, just a shame one has to go to such lengths to get what you would think is very useful information and would warrant a place in the object's description.